# Manually render dynamically generated Google 'plus one' button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-plus, google-plus-one

Here's the scene:

- The webpage doesn't have a google+ button.
- User clicks a button.
- AJAX request is sent which loads some text and the google+ button (`<g:plusone href="http://www.website.com"></g:plusone>`)
  into a `div`.
- I can see when I look at the code that it is there, but it is not rendering.

I've heard that this might be useful:
`gapi.plusone.go();`

But I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Since you already have the g+ div in place - all you have to do is invoke the render by calling `gapi.plusone.go()`. It is better to pass it the id the of the container div.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track. `gapi.plusone.go()` is one way to explicitly render the +1 button. Here's a code snippet from the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#example-explicit-render) that illustrates another method using `gapi.plusone.render()`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>+1 Demo: Explicit render</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
      {"parsetags": "explicit"}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function renderPlusone() {
        gapi.plusone.render("plusone-div");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onClick="renderPlusone();">Render the +1 button</a>
    <div id="plusone-div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript API is further documented [elsewhere on the previously linked page](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#jsapi).

Comment: Thanks! Another problem that i was having (silly me) was that I was calling the render/go as soon as the page loaded... I have added a little timeout to wait for the ajax request to finish - and it works now. Thanks for your help!